# Detection of naturally equivalent functors

Tags: category-theory

Recall that two functors $F,G:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$  are called natural equivalent if there exists a natural transformation $\eta=(\eta_X)$ from $F$ to $G$ such that $\eta_X$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{D}$ for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ (see [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation)).

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category (specially, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a directed graph without multiple arcs) and $F,G:\mathcal{C}\to \mathbf{Set}$ be two covariant functors. Is there any necessary and sufficient condition for detecting that $F$ and $G$ are natural equivalent?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, this is much too general. More can be said with more hypotheses, e.g. that $F, G$ are representable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edit the question and add some new assumption. However I think that when $\mathcal{C}$ is a directed graph without multiple arcs, the functors are not necessarily representable.

Comment: Even in this case I don't think there are any shortcuts, you just have to check equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and regards

Comment: well of course we should require $F(X)$ has the same cardinality as $G(X)$ for all $X$ as a necessary condition. It's definitely insufficient, though.